# Filesystem Hierarchy , private forensic analysis

Tags: directory-structure

I wanted to refresh my memories and ran the command in the terminal

```
find / -mtime some_date -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' 2>/dev/null | sort -r
```

and I see a large number of files, drivers, processes in the output.
And I’m curious, which of this was modified by the system without the participation of the user, and which with the participation?
For example.

```
07:47:19.0000000000 /var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-jammy-universe/*
```

The icons (there are several of them from different programs) are in the folder, but the programs on computer are not.
Is it possible to unambiguously confirm user manipulations, for example, installing, launching a program, or deleting it, or opening a website ?
or for example

```
20:17:18.0000000000 /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/libsasl2-modules
20:17:18.0000000000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2
```

and more  drivers at the same time.
This chain ends with the line

```
20:17:18.0000000000 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsasl2-modules-db:amd64.md5sums
```

Who is the initiator of the process here, the user or the system?
And so on... In general, I would like to know from the analysis of which directories\files\processes one can draw an unambiguous conclusion: there was a user here. Maybe it’s better to use the commands `-ctime`,
`-atime` and which directories of processes to look at? Maybe there is a manual on this topic?
I would appreciate any answers.

Comment: With the name `swcatalog`, I would imagine it would _not_ contain the actual applications but just details about them (names, descriptions, screenshots, and, as you see, icons)

Comment: I corrected it, not only are the programs not in this folder, they are not on the computer at all. And in that folder there are only 2 subfolders, icons and Yaml.

Answer (score 1):

I am... Honestly not entirely sure *what* you're asking here, but in the case of the last three files you mention, it's pretty obvious that they were all created/modified at the same time, by the same process -- namely, the process that installed the latest update to the amd64 architecture version of`libsasl2-modules-db`.

(From `apt show libsasl2-modules-db`:

> Description: Cyrus SASL - pluggable authentication modules (DB)

> This is the Cyrus SASL API implementation, version 2.1. See package
> libsasl2-2 and RFC 2222 for more information.  .  This package
> provides the DB plugin, which supports Berkeley DB lookups.

)

`/var/lib/dpkg/info` contains various ancillary ('INFO') files that help dpkg figure out what it needs to do and/or check when installing, updating or removing a given software package. Specifically, the `.md5sums` file will contain the MD5 checksums for each file in the package, so that dpkg can verify that it wasn't tampered with.

`/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/` is a drop-in directory for the `logcheck` service that packages can use to add pertinent configuration snippets as needed; apparently libsasl2-modules-db generates various bits of syslog info that are best ignored by logcheck in order to avoid an excess of false positives.

Finally, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2` is the actual payload -- the shared object library file for SASL that lets it interface with the Berkeley DB system.

All of those were placed there at the same time, by the action that installed or updated the `libsasl2-modules-db:amd64` package. This could have been an automated upgrade or a manual action; there isn't enough information to tell. I'd recommend checking for activity in `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/` and `/var/log/apt/`

Likewise, the directory `/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-jammy-universe` is almost certainly populated more or less automatically by software packages when they're installed and their icons are added or linked into that directory.

Like I said at the start of this, I'm not sure what you're looking for, but a simple "search for all files that were recently modified or added across the entire filesystem" command is not going to be much help - modern linux systems aren't nearly static enough for that.

If you want to do serious forensics you're going to have to learn to sort the signal from the noise, and the only way to do so is to learn how the components that make up your system work.

Comment: Due to the length of time, there are no logs for that period.
Regarding the swcatalog directory, I understand what you wrote, but as I clarified above, there is a modification of about 10 icons, but no of the 10 programs on the computer. It is unlikely that all of them were modified simultaneously down  in the original places on the sites. All the same, probably as a result of actions on the computer. What action ? Whose? That is the question.

Comment: If they were all modified at the same time, they were probably dropped in there by the same process. Almost certainly the process that installed swcatalog. Again, without more information it's hard to say anything definite -- and you're coming at it with the exact wrong attitude.

Comment: To clarify: you're looking for what you think are anomalies, and when you find them your first assumption appears to be "this must be MALFEASANCE". This kind of scattershot hunting isn't going to get you anywhere. Learn how your system works. Learn its rhythm. *then* you'll be equipped to realize when something is off.

Comment: By definition, I cannot have the right approach. I'm a regular Windows user, and out of some necessity I'm learning a laptop with Ubuntu. And I just want to understand some things that I thought were simple. But it turns out everything is very complicated.
It’s not my case to take a young fighter’s course from scratch.
Briefly, once again: I want to understand, the analysis of which directories, subdirectories, files can clearly say: the initiator is the user.

Comment: Aside from `/home/<user>/` *there is no such thing*. There's no shortcut here. You'll need to learn the patterns of your system before you'll be able to see what doesn't fit.

Comment: Ok, can I, as a noob, reason as follows? Let's look at the Snap directory and subdirectories, here we can assume that everything here is automated, without user participation. And we can even assume that the programs whose icons were described above were in Snap packages. Otherwise, where would the icons come from if the directory in which they are located is created by the system. But since there are no logs for that time, we can simply assume that those programs were downloaded in Snap packages, unpacked, updated with the date that is higher.

Comment: But there are actually no programs on the computer. Can we assume that they were deleted later than that date, or is it precisely the date of the last modification of the files that is the date of deletion? I'm interested in forensics in exactly this way.

Comment: You're making less and less sense with each additional comment and I'm not sure it's just your poor grasp of the language.